# JSON string altered during post request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to send following Javascript object from one local nodejs (express) instance to another.

```
var v = {
    items: [{
        id: "fil1",
        values: [
            { key: "123", timestamp: 333, value: "aaa" },
            { key: "123", timestamp: 333, value: "aaa" },
            { key: "123", timestamp: 333, value: "aaa" },
            { key: "123", timestamp: 333, value: "aaa" }
        ]
    }]
};
```

I use the following post request where `request = require('request')`, and `params` is the JSON.stringified version of the object `v` above.

```
var performPostRequest = function (ip, port, endpoint, params, callback) {
var url = "http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + endpoint;
request.post({
    url: url,
    form: params,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, body);
    }
    if (body) {
        callback(err, JSON.parse(body));
    }
});
};
```

The receiving endpoint looks like this:

```
router.post('/values', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);

    res.status(201).send("");
});
```

Where router is express.Router().

So, to my question : **When printing `JSON.stringify(v)` at the sender, the result is a string matching the object v, but when printing the body of the request at the receiving endpoint, the string is messed up (see below). What am I doing wrong?**

`JSON.stringify(v)` on sender:

```
{"items":[{"id":"fil1","values":[{"key":"123","timestamp":333,"value":"aaa"},{"key":"123","timestamp":333,"value":"aaa"},{"key":"123","timestamp":333,"value":"aaa"},{"key":"123","timestamp":333,"value":"aaa"}]}]}
```

`req.body` at receiver:

```
{ '{"items":': { '{"key":"123","timestamp":333,"value":"aaa"},{"key":"123","timestamp":333,"value":"aaa"},{"key":"123","timestamp":333,"value":"aaa"},{"key":"123","timestamp":333,"value":"aaa"}': '' } }
```

Comment: `params` is a string? The [request docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback) indicate that the value of the `form` option should be an object or a querystring, not a JSON string. Did you mean to use `body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send JSON using [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) using `json` option that takes care of everything, from [request doc](https://github.com/request/request) :

> json - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds
>   Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the
>   response body as JSON.

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        items: [{
            id: "fil1",
            values: [
                { key: "123", timestamp: 333, value: "aaa" },
                { key: "123", timestamp: 333, value: "aaa" },
                { key: "123", timestamp: 333, value: "aaa" },
                { key: "123", timestamp: 333, value: "aaa" }
            ]
        }]
    };
};

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        callback(err, body);
    }
    if (body) {
        callback(error, body);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bertrand, i will try. Can the "form" option should not be used for json?

Comment: From the same [readme](https://github.com/request/request) : `form - when passed an object or a querystring, this sets body to a querystring representation of value, and adds Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded header. When passed no options, a FormData instance is returned (and is piped to request)`. So no, it should not be used for Json data but for url encoded data